# Have the quotas for Forge Design Automation changed?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

In the past, I recall that there were max numbers for input sizes and numbers of inputs, however I can no longer find that info in the documentation. Do these limits still exist? The only mention I can find of them is in the Inventor release notes in the DA documentation:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/change_history/inventor_release_notes/

The quotas page linked can't be found.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/quotas/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no limits for max numbers for input sizes and number of inputs, etc. anymore.
The quotas information can be found [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/rate-limits/da-rate-limits/#quotas).

Comment: Does that mean there are also no limits to outputs?

Comment: No limits to outputs too. All quotas are listed in the link post above.

Comment: Thanks so much, Emma. Last comment, are changes like this what the changelog in the documentation is for? It would be nice to be able to check if something has changed when it can no longer be found.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion, Kate! We will keep mind to update the changelog. The changes usually can be found [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/change_history/revit_release_notes/)